# Installer is unable to instantiate the file ...\KEY_XE.reg. The file does not appear to exist

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I keep getting this error when trying to install Oracle Express edition on Windows 64.  I searched online and the only posts I found were for a missing registry entry.  The actual file is missing in my case.  I have uninstalled, rebooted, and re-installed several times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All you need is :"Just click OK" and throw it away. It is not a blocking issue to install it.

Comment: Clicking OK, will not work in all cases. We need to add KEY_XE.reg file as per this blog http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/09/13/oracle-11g-xe-installer/